# RPI - Rainbow Screen after SSH reboot - Parrot Security ARMHF

Tags: pi-2, parrot

I cant seem to find a definitive solution to my problem.

I have learned now by this THIRD occasion that I cannot simply "reboot" from SSH without killing my RPI Parrot installation and having to start from scratch.

When I disconnect power and reconnect I get the "rainbow screen of death" to bastardise a Windows term.

Is there anything I can do to save the installation at this point?

Comment: Parrot is a specialised distro.  They must be the best to ask for support.

Comment: I did this last shut down by the book so to speak and still ended up with the same result so it may indeed be something specific to that OS but I haven't been able to find anyone report something similar :/

Comment: what is your "by the book shutdown method"? `sudo shutdown -h now` and then waiting a reasonable amount of time.